# Read/write ble characteristics from/to particular service

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I have several services with different UUIDs, but with the same characteristics UUIDs. I'm not sure what characteristic will be got if I call `rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID)`. How to do it the best? I can find a particular service from the services list and then deal with BluetoothGattService and its characteristics, but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is more than one characteristic with the same `UUID` the only API that allows the user to control which characteristic will be used are:

- `RxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)`
- `RxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic, byte[])`
- `RxBleConnection.setupNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)`
- `RxBleConnection.setupIndication(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)`
- Other that expose usage of `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`

To get a reference to the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` the user should search the result of `RxBleConnection.discoverServices()` — first to get the needed `BluetoothGattService` and then search the service for the needed `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`